# ltrace prints only two calls

Tags: debugging, gdb, ltrace

I ran **ltrace** on a Word processor and opened a sample file, but surprisingly got only two calls.

```
__libc_start_main(0x8048820, 1, 0xbfe08844, 0x8048850, 0x80488b0 <unfinished ...>
_ZN10AP_UnixApp4mainEPKciPPc(0x8048910, 1, 0xbfe08844, 0xb61feff4, 0x8048850) = 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

Shouldn't ltrace print all library calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ltrace` only intercepts calls from the main executable (`abiword` here) to other shared libraries, but does not intercept calls from one shared library to another.

For `abiword`, the `main` function doesn't actually do much:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400a70 <+0>: mov    %rsi,%rdx
   0x0000000000400a73 <+3>: mov    %edi,%esi
   0x0000000000400a75 <+5>: mov    $0x400b6c,%edi
   0x0000000000400a7a <+10>:    jmpq   0x400950 <_ZN10AP_UnixApp4mainEPKciPPc@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

As you can see, it simply does a `return AP_UnixApp::main(argc, "abiword", argv);`, and all the real activity happens in the library that implements `AP_UnixApp::main` (in my case, in `/usr/lib/libabiword-2.8.so`).

On a Fedora system, you can try using `frysk` instead. In particular, this:

```
ftrace -sym '*' abiword
```

produces a (very long) trace, beginning with:

```
528.528 attached /usr/bin/abiword
528.528 call #libpthread.so.0#_init(0x1, 0x7fffa8ba5bd8, 0x7fffa8ba5be8, 0x7fffa8ba5be8, 0x1f25bc2, 0x7)
528.528  call #libpthread.so.0#__pthread_initialize_minimal(0x1, 0x7fffa8ba5bd8, 0x7fffa8ba5be8, 0x7fffa8ba5be8, 0x1f25bc2, 0x7)
528.528   call #libpthread.so.0#__libc_sigaction(0x20, 0x7fffa8ba5a70, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1f25bc2, 0x7)
528.528   call #libpthread.so.0#__libc_sigaction(0x21, 0x7fffa8ba5a70, 0x0, 0x7f32501f27b0, 0x0, 0x7)
528.528   call #libc.so.6#getrlimit(0x3, 0x7fffa8ba5b10, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x0, 0x7) = 0
528.528   call #libc.so.6#sysconf(0x1e, 0x7fffa8ba5b10, 0x3f, 0x30220e7b17, 0x0, 0x7)
528.528    call #libc.so.6#getpagesize(0x1e, 0x7fffa8ba5b10, 0xfffffffffff51435, 0x30220e7b17, 0x0, 0x7) = 4096
528.528   leave #libc.so.6#sysconf = 4096
528.528   call #libc.so.6#__libc_dl_error_tsd(0x1e, 0x7fffa8ba5b10, 0x800000, 0x2a40, 0x0, 0x7) = 139854069229848
...
```

Ftrace documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/frysk/manpages/ftrace.1.html).